# excel conditional formatting on cell versus adjecant cell

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I have two columns with names.
I would like to change color on the corresponding cell where value is not the same as in first column.

```
    A   B
1   Lars    Lars
2   Erik    Erik
3   Niels   Jens
4   Brian   Brian
```

In the above case B3 should be highlighted.

I have looked all over (really - all over) the internet - and the closest I got was Column A to be highlighted if there was a difference.

Comment: then used what they did for column A but replace all column A references with column B references.

Comment: Tried that. And the formatting changed to the complete B column - not just B3

Comment: what was the formula you were using in your conditional formatting

Comment: Old one - missing. Current (playing around as  we speak) is =ISERROR(MATCH($A2;$B2;0)) which gives some weird results (Must investigate further..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formula in conditional formatting. I have used `VLOOKUP` You can use `MATCH` as well

```
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B1,$A:$A,1,0)<>B1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to select column B, go to Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use formula to determine which cells to format, and then I would put in the following formula:

```
=D1<>C1
```

Please, note that this is without dollar signs, this is very important.

Comment: should modify the formula to refer to the first row in column B, and add a tid bit about having first row to last row of data selected before you go to conditional formatting so that when you enter the formula for the active cell, it will update the cell addresses as the formula gets applied to the selected cells.